# htaccess, allow a single internal ip address

Tags: .htaccess, configuration, server

Good morning,

I have configured my .htaccess file as:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 65.43.173.125
```

Do you know if there is any way to allow a single internal IP address of that external IP address?

Something like

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from 65.43.173.125 But Only -> 192.168.0.53
```

I know both the external IP and internal IP that I want to allow.

Thanks in advance!

[IP address provided in the examples is random]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.0.53
```

This will deny access to everyone from within the IP 65.43.173.125 except for 192.168.0.53

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why should it works? Do you mean that I have to add this code to my code?

Comment: This would go into your .htaccess file.